# Change the way how HttpValueCollection encodes the arguments

Tags: c#, .net, http, web

```
var original = "АБ";

var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("");
query["Arg"] = original;
var tmp1 = query.ToString();
```

The code above (which is the recommended way of building query strings) encodes the argument as `Arg=%u0410%u0411`
However, the target API doesn't accept this argument and demands it to be encoded this way: `Arg=%D0%90%D0%91`
Is it possible to make HttpValueCollection use this encoding?

Answer (score 3):

There is a comment in the source code of HttpValueCollection that explains your problem:

```
// DevDiv #762975: <form action> and other similar URLs are mangled since we use non-standard %uXXXX encoding.
// We need to use standard UTF8 encoding for modern browsers to understand the URLs.
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpValueCollection.cs,9938b1dbd553e753,references

It looks like this behavior can be controlled with an appSetting in web.config. To get the behavior you want add this:

```
<add key="aspnet:DontUsePercentUUrlEncoding" value="true" />
```

If you are targeting .NET 4.5.2+ this value should be set to true by default.

You could use in the [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  class in the `System.Net.Http` namespace instead. Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
string query;
using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Arg", "АБ")
}))
{
    query = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

Console.WriteLine(query);
```

Also you can google "querystring builder c#" tosee solutions that others have come up with.

Comment: 4.6.2 - still getting this non-standard encoding. And unfortunately, my application is a client rather than website so this web.config tweak isn't applicable.

Comment: @user626528 It looks like adding the `aspnet:DontUsePercentUUrlEncoding` entry to `<appSettings>` works even in a client app if you put it in the app's .config file. I have just observed this in a console app.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is using UTF-8 for encoding where as your requirement uses some other codepage.

Just use the overload with the Encoding parameter (you need to choose your encoding which you need, for a list see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string, encoding);
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms150047(v=vs.110).aspx)